# about BPMN: Two times the same actor in one process?

Tags: process, diagram, bpmn, business-process-management

In BPMN is it allowed for me to use the same actor twice in a process scheme? As you can see in the example below, I'm using Actor A twice - is this acceptable?

[image: Example of using Actor A twice]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This question is off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming, and should be closed [blatantly off-topic]. Please take some time to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

The [BPMN 2.0 specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0.2/PDF) states that *"[t]he meaning of the Lanes is up to the modeler*" (page 305/page 335 in PDF). This means whatever you do with the semantics of your lanes is compliant with the spec. Consequently, you *can* have multiple lanes that depict the same actor in one process.

However, I don't recommend this, because it will confuse readers.
Your specific example creates an additional problem: your process interacts with one and the same actor (*Actor A*) in two different ways (via a message flow, respectively via a sequence flow). This typically makes little sense. And if there is a reason for this, you should ask yourself if *Actor A (lane)* is really exactly the same as *Actor A (pool)*. Perhaps the two elements stand for the same person (or group of persons), but for different *roles*? Then, the labels should clarify this. Also, in your example the use of pools is inconsistent: the label of the pool *Process A* specifies the process it contains, while the label of the pool *Actor A* specifies its actor.

Answer (score 0):

Remember: BPMN have two type of diagram: descriptive/analytical and executable (see 2.2.1 BPMN Process Types).  It is totally different context and meaning.

I hope you ask about analytical model. Your diagram shows Process A including two actors A and B, and Proces (remember pool means process not actor) named Actor A. 
1. it is not a problem if two companies have actor e.g. Salesman, 
2. it is a problem when you use word "actor" as a name of a process.